# Struggling to find way to implement conditional formatting in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Basically, I am trying to log my sleep wake up times into a google sheet and conditionally format it so that if the time is less than (earlier than) or equal the time of the previous *successful* day (aka one that's coloured green), the box will be coloured green. However, if the time is later than the previous day, it will be coloured red.

[image: Attached screenshot of error]

My error is that I'd want it to ignore the cells coloured red and just judge the lowest time value out of the ones coloured green. As you can see in the photo, The `8:49:00` should be red but is green due to being earlier than the day before. My 2 thoughts were:

a) To find the minumum out of the range of cells above it in that column that were coloured green, and compare it to that.

b) To disregard any cell coloured green and make it move onto the cell above it repeatedly until there was a green one to compare it to that.

I am very new to more complex Excel/Google Sheets implementation and any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the conditional formatting equation I came up with:

To highlight cells that do not pass muster:

```
=AND($A3>MIN($A$3:$A3),$A3<>0)
```

To highlight cells that do pass test:

```
=AND($A3<=MIN($A$3:$A3),$A3<>0)
```

**First Equation:**

For each cell in my range, A3:A100 I am checking if 1) my cell is less than the minimum between the start of the range and $A(myCurrentRow) AND that the value of cell is not 0 (we could set up dynamic range to....)

**Second Equation:**

Here we are doing the same thing but simply flipping the > to a < and adding an = to account for the fact that at times this cell was the earliest wake up time in the range

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. The explantion was really simple and helpful. Cheers again